# Tensorflow quantization

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to optimize a graph using Tensorflow's transform_graph tool. I tried optimizing the graph from [MultiNet](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/MultiNet) (and others with similar encoder-decoder architectures). However, the optimized graph is actually slower when using quantize_weights, and even much slower when using quantize_nodes. From Tensorflow's documentation, there may be no improvements, or it may even be slower, when quantizing. Any idea if this is normal with the graph/software/hardware below?

Here is my system information for your reference:

- OS Platform and Distribution: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- TensorFlow installed from: using TF source code (CPU) for graph conversion, using binary-python(GPU) for inference
- TensorFlow version: both using r1.3
- Python version: 2.7
- Bazel version: 0.6.1
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 8.0/6.0 (inference only)
- GPU model and memory: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

I can post all the scripts used to reproduce if necessary.

Comment: Can you please provide an example snippet code on how did you actually quantized the graph ? was the model quality same after quantization ? I have a frozen graph (or saved model) , that i want to quantize and run inference , can you  provide me some pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like quantization in Tensorflow only happens on CPUs. See: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2807

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem in PC enviroment. My model is 9 times slower than not quantize.

But when I porting my quantized model into android application, its ok to speed up.

Seems like current only work on CPU and only ARM base CPU such as android phone.